# Making a WYSIWYG form field in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm currently practicing making a blog in Django and I'd love to have WYSIWYG form field in Django but obviously it's not pre-built in Django and I know for a fact that I can create custom fields I just can't seem to find the right way to do it.

Any tutorials or tips would be appreciated. I don't want to use a package I want to do it myself just for the sake of learning.

Comment: This isn't something you can do yourself. It requires a whole lot of complex JavaScript.

Comment: okay, then what's the best package to do this? also is there's a way I can do something on adding something new on admin panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/

This tutorial will show you how to get the blogs on your admin panel